# Nextjs build errors, verbose logging shows nothing

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm using the latest version Nextjs. The project is running fine when testing and running in developer mode. When I try a production build `npx next build --debug` I get the error below. The output doesn't tell me much about what the problem is. Any ideas how to get the verbose information from this error?

HookWebpackError: Expected an opening square bracket.

> Build error occurred
> Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
> at /Users/xxx/projects/nextjs/my-next-website/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:17:924
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/xxx/projects/nextjs/my-next-website/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)

Comment: Could you add the whole trace?

Comment: Hi Simon, that is the whole trace?

Comment: Unless there is some way to log more information?

Comment: I just started getting this error too. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: To be honest i didn't go any further with iit. I went back to Gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

`npx` might load a different version of next than your local dependency. I wouldn't recommend running this with npx. Instead make an npm script, or use `npm bin next`, or if you use yarn you can use local binaries with `yarn next`.

Comment: ok valid point. If I run `yarn next build` i still get the same error